# I wrote a thesis for my undergraduate degree - it was published but not in a journal. Is it still relevant to cite?

Tags: thesis, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I wrote a thesis involving not-quite-graduate-level research prior to graduating with my undergraduate degree. It was presented at a conference [by another researcher from our lab], and not published in a journal or peer-reviewed publication. I have cited it for several years as part of my resume - at what point is it no longer relevant to include?

Note for clarification: I have had only one other publication in the [approximately ten] years since completion of my undergrad work.

Comment: _at what point is it no longer relevant to include?_ — Never.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the research was *original* and *academic*, then I would say keep it in there if it's relevant to the role that you see yourself working in. If it was a team effort, make sure you cite it as such. Since it wasn't officially published, I'd suggest linking to it online (and hosting it somewhere if it isn't already hosted by your academic institution).

Of course, I'm not really authoritative on this type of thing, but if I were evaluating prospective employees, I'd love to be able to see relevant examples of their work even if they weren't formally published.

Comment: Indeed, although some sort of vetting is nice, it's not always possible. Seeing that you did some work, with or without certification or status-point scoring, imparts information. And put it on-line so that it can truly impart information.

Comment: The research was _original_ and _academic_. I'd like to be working in those fields in the future (research, academic, and the thesis topic).
Thanks for the suggestion to host it as well - I'll have to investigate how to get a copy of this thesis (and my other publications as well).